# Custom fields vs DataFields in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Does anyone know the difference between using the Data Field in Standard set of fields versus defining a Custom field ?

JK

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about envelope custom fields - those are invisible during signing and should be used for meta-data only.

Here is a good reason to use envelope custom fields:
A loan origination system might have a loan ID and would put the loan ID as a meta data on all the DocuSign envelopes that pertain to that loan. This makes searching and cross linking easy.

Here is a good use case for regular "Secure Fields" or "Form Fields" or "Data Fields":
A system has address for a particular signer and wants to pre-populate that data for signing, but maybe give the signer an option to correct it.  You put the data field on and then the user can fill it out or update it.

Hope this helps.